# java.lang.ClassCastException: android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatButton cannot be cast to android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton

Tags: java, android, xml, classcastexception, floating-action-button

It is not a clean and rebuild issue AT ALL! Make module will not 
resolve this issue either. This is the only 
FlotingActionButton I'm using in my code. One solution said this only 
occurs with an anchor parameter but as you can see I am not using one 
so I dont know what to make of it.

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/activity_main"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/coverpic"
    tools:context="com.android.nohiccupsbeta.MainActivity">

    <android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
        android:id="@+id/effects_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
        <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
            android:id="@+id/fab"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_gravity="top|end"
            android:layout_marginTop="400dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="15dp"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_book"
            app:backgroundTint="@color/primary_color" />

    </android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>

    <android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
        android:id="@+id/take_test"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
        <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
            android:id="@+id/fab2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
            android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
            app:backgroundTint="@color/primary_color"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_handcuffs" />

    </android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

This is the JAVA code. I tried importing the Coordinator Layout but 
that is not possible. I also tried declaring the fab var differently 
just to get the same error :

```
    package com.android.nohiccupsbeta;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


        FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton)findViewById(R.id.fab);
        fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this, pageone.class));
            }
        });


        FloatingActionButton fab2 = (FloatingActionButton)findViewById(R.id.fab2);
        fab2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this, BacTest.class));
            }
        });
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2):

Your second FloatingActionButton does not have an id, and the one you are trying to cast into a FAB is the CoordinatorLayout.

So, you should set an id in your layout for your fabs like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/activity_main"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/coverpic">

    <android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
        android:id="@+id/effects_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
        <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
            android:id="@+id/fab"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_gravity="top|end"
            android:layout_marginTop="400dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="15dp"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_book"
            app:backgroundTint="@color/primary_color" />

    </android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>

    <android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
        android:id="@+id/take_test"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
        <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
            android:id="@+id/fab2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
            android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
            app:backgroundTint="@color/primary_color"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_handcuffs" />

    </android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

and your fabs to match the new ids like this

```
FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton)findViewById(R.id.fab);
FloatingActionButton fab2 = (FloatingActionButton)findViewById(R.id.fab2);
```

Comment: It has an i.d . I gave it a try anyway and put the id under the floating action button and gave the coordinator layout a different id. I got the same error

Comment: You have the same issue with the first fab. Updating my answer with working code

Comment: OK I changed the code now I'm getting a different error message in the log java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton.setOnClickListener(android.view.View$OnClickListener)' on a null object reference
                                                                             at com.android.nohiccupsbeta.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:18)

Comment: do you mind updating your code on the question? for both the activity and layout

Comment: So, your new code is working for me . 
As I can see there should not be problems. Are you sure you are referencing the correct layout file ?

Comment: I am referencing to the correct file. Everything in my manifest file is correct. I have no idea whats going wrong

Comment: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton.setOnClickListener(android.view.View$OnClickListener)' on a null object reference
                                                                               at com.android.nohiccupsbeta.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:18)

Comment: I resolved issue yesterday. I failed to change the large, small, XML's. I only changed the main one. Thank you for your assistance.